# Display Loading Before Redirecting to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

I'm Developing a bank transaction page. 
On Page_load() part I request a token from bank and then my page redirects to bank for user payment.

The problem is when My page loads, it redirects to bank page before displaying current animated gif to notify the user that he/she is redirecting to bank page.

On Which part of Page Life Cycle I should make the request to be sure that Current HTML Page Loads completely and displays to user before redirects to bank page ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("bank.aspx?au=" + authority);
}
```

I already tested Page_PreInit, OnInit, Page_InitComplete and OnPreRender.

Answer (score 2):

You can user javascript for this purpose:

```
 function redirect() {
        document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.href = 'Default.aspx'
        }, 2000);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="message" style="background:red;padding:10px;color:White;display:none;width:100px">
 Redirecting....
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="redirect();" value="Click to redirect"/>
```

DOME : http://jsfiddle.net/rDEw3/

In your senario you may call it like this;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "redirect", "redirect();", true);

}
```

Comment: I agree with Irfan's answer, but perhaps a better idea would be to redirect the user immediately to a buffer page, and place the javascript script on **that** page instead. Buffer pages are a good idea when you don't want the page to be reloaded. Just have the page say "Please wait while your transaction is being processed . . ." and have javascript redirect the user after a few seconds.

Comment: Is there any other solutions which can help ?